# UITextView Alignment like UILabel

Tags: objective-c, alignment, uitextview

Is there any way to change start-typing point of UITextview like UILabel?

I would like to type fonts starting point from the center on UITextView rather than default point from the upper left.

Anybody help me out kindly?

Cheers,

[image]

Comment: Is possible to effect on typing point using constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this issue by observing the contentsize of UITextView, when there is any change in the contentSize, update the contentOffset.

Add observer as follows:

```
[textview addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:NULL];
```

Handle the observer action as follows:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
     UITextView *txtview = object;
     CGFloat topoffset = ([txtview bounds].size.height - [txtview contentSize].height * [txtview zoomScale])/2.0;
     topoffset = ( topoffset < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topoffset );
     txtview.contentOffset = (CGPoint){.x = 0, .y = -topoffset};
}
```

To make the textview text horizontally center, select the textview from .xib class and go to the library and in that set Alignment as center.

Comment: Thank you vey much for sharing your codes. I will try these and tell you see what happens later! Quick response from me.